# AWS SQS redrive policy, which end of the queue do messges go to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

In an AWS SQS standard queue you can set a redrive policy which will cause messages to be retried if there is a failure where by the message is not deleted from the queue.

In my case i have > 1,000,000 messages on the queue which take a couple of hours to process. When a message fails and is put back on the queue will it be put to the end of the queue or the front. Will the messages get retried in a minute or two or in two or three hours when all the other messages have been processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee which order messages are returned, so once you return a message it could be retried immediately, when all the others are processed, or anywhere in the middle - there may be some undocumented common patterns for when retries happen, but its not something you can count on or design around.

> **Q: Does Amazon SQS provide message ordering?**
>
> Yes. FIFO (first-in-first-out) queues preserve the exact order in
>   which messages are sent and received. If you use a FIFO queue, you
>   don't have to place sequencing information in your messages. For more
>   information, see FIFO Queue Logic in the Amazon SQS Developer Guide.
>
> Standard queues provide a loose-FIFO capability that attempts to
>   preserve the order of messages. However, because standard queues are
>   designed to be massively scalable using a highly distributed
>   architecture, receiving messages in the exact order they are sent is
>   not guaranteed.

https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/

Comment: I thought that might have been the case. Do you know where i might be able to read about this, the AWS docs didn't say anything about it (not that i could find)

Comment: Thanks, I have read that faq before about how the standard queues work with regards to ordering of messages placed on the queue. What i could not find though was any documentation about how the redrive messages worked with regards to ordering. Did you come to your original answer through experience rather than reading docs?